# In Pee-Wee's Big Adventure, Did Pee-Wee Use the Boomerang Bow-Tie?

Tags: plot-explanation, pee-wees-big-adventure

Near the beginning of Pee-Wee's Big Adventure, Pee-Wee buys a loud horn for his bike from Chuck's Bike-O-Rama and three items from Mario's Joke Shop: 1. Trick Gum; 2. Headlight Glasses; and 3. A red boomerang bow-tie. Pee-Wee uses each of these items later in the movie with the possible exception of the boomerang bow-tie.

My Question:

- In Pee-Wee's Big Adventure, did Pee-Wee use the boomerang bow-tie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, he did not.  In the Theatrical release, anyway.  A scene was filmed during the chase on Warner Brothers' lot where Pee Wee *did* use the bowtie, but it was cut from the movie.  This appears as one of the deleted scenes on the DVD release.

Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089791/alternateversions)